# Group by, Pivot with multiple columns and condition count

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Agreement": ["Peace", "Peace", "Love", "Love", "Sun","Sun","Sun"],
    "country1": ["USA", "UK", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy","India","China"],
    "country2": ["Canada", "France", "Portugal", "Italy","India","Spain","UK"],
    "EP1": [1, 0, 1, 0, 0,1,1],
    "EP2": [0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0],
    "EP3": [1, 0, 1, 0,1,1,1]
})
```

I would like to group by or pivot so that I get the count of times a country is in an agreement with at least one EP equal or greater than 1. I would like as output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Country": ["USA", "UK", "Germany", "Spain", "Italy","India","China", "Canada","France","Portugal"],
    "Agreement with at least one EP per country": [1, 1, 1, 1,1,2,1,1,0,1]
})
```

I have tried with pivot and group by and loop but I never reach the desired output. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarize 'EPx' columns in 'Agreement' then flatten your dataframe. Finally group by Country to count the number of agreement.

```
cols = ['country1', 'country2', 'Agreement']
out = (df.assign(Agreement=df.filter(like='EP').any(axis=1))[cols]
         .melt('Agreement', value_name='Country')
         .groupby('Country', sort=False)['Agreement'].sum().reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
    Country  Agreement
0       USA          1
1        UK          1
2   Germany          1
3     Spain          1
4     Italy          1
5     India          2
6     China          1
7    Canada          1
8    France          0
9  Portugal          1
```

**Update**

> I am interested in the count of times a country is in a unique agreement with at least one EP equal or greater than 1.

```
cols = ['country1', 'country2', 'Agreement']
out = (df.assign(Agreement=df.filter(like='EP').any(axis=1))[cols]
         .melt('Agreement', value_name='Country')
         .groupby('Country', sort=False)['Agreement'].max().astype(int).reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
    Country  Agreement
0       USA          1
1        UK          1
2   Germany          1
3     Spain          1
4     Italy          1
5     India          1
6     China          1
7    Canada          1
8    France          0
9  Portugal          1
```